# want to execute a single step multiple times

Tags: maven, cucumber, bdd

I have written a feature file in cucumber with java for login operation.
I want to perform only login operation multiple times once application has been launched without closing the application.

Here's feature file

```
Feature: Login Scenario

Scenario Outline: Execute me multiple times
    Given I open the application
    When I enter `"<username>"` and `"<password>"`
    Then I click on Login button
    And I close the application

Examples:
  | username | password  |
  | user1    | password1 |
  | user2    | password2 |
  | user3    | password3 |
  | user4    | password4 |
  | user5    | password5 |
```

In this case every time app is being launched and closed. But I want to launch and close only once and perform multiple login operations.

**Runner class:**

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
@CucumberOptions(features="feature",glue= {"steps"})
public class TestRunner {}
```

And Step definitions:

```
public class TestMe {
WebDriver driver;
String chrome="webdriver.chrome.driver";
String path="./drivers/chromedriver1.exe";

@Given("^I open the application$")
public void i_open_the_application() throws Throwable {
    System.setProperty(chrome, path);
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/AZ/Desktop/webpages/loginPage.html");
}
@When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_enter_and(String user, String pass) throws Throwable {
    driver.findElement(By.id("user")).sendKeys(user);
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(pass);
}
@Then("^I click on Login button$")
public void i_click_on_Login_button() throws Throwable {
    driver.findElement(By.id("btn")).click();
}

@Then("^I close the application$")
public void i_close_the_application() throws Throwable {
    driver.close();
}

}
```

WebPage HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
Username<input type="text" id="user"></br></br>
Password<input type="password" id="pass"></br></br>
<input type="button" value="Login" id="btn">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected Results: Launch and close only once and login operation multiple times.

Actual Results: Multiple times Launch ,login operation and close.

Answer (score 0):

**Outcome :** Below approach would launch & close browser only once and perform multiple login attempts

**Focus Area :** You shall exclude browser launching & closing code from scenario outline as we are going to keep it under annotations **@BeforeClass** and **@AfterClass**

```
Scenario Outline: Execute me multiple times
 When I enter "<username>" and "<password>"
 Then I click on Login button

Examples:

  | username | password  |
  | user1    | password1 |
  | user2    | password2 |
  | user3    | password3 |
  | user4    | password4 |
  | user5    | password5 |
```

**TestRunner.Java**

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "feature",
                     glue = {"steps" },
                   plugin = { "pretty","json:target/cucumber-json/cucumber.json",
                            "junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.xml", "html:target/cucumber-reports"},
               monochrome = true)

public class TestRunner {

WebDriver driver;
    String chrome="webdriver.chrome.driver";
    String path="./drivers/chromedriver1.exe";

    @BeforeClass
    void launchBrowser() {
        System.setProperty(chrome, path);
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        DriverManager.setWebDriver(driver);
        driver.get("file:///C:/Users/AZ/Desktop/webpages/loginPage.html");
    }

    @AfterClass
    void closeBrowser() {       
         driver.close();
    }
}
```

**DriverManager.Java**

```
public class DriverManager {

    public static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> dr = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return dr.get();
    }

    public static void setWebDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        dr.set(driver);
    }
}
```

**StepDefinition.Java**

```
class StepDefinition
{

WebDriver driver;

public StepDefinition() {
        driver = DriverManager.get();
    }

@When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_enter_and(String user, String pass) throws Throwable {
    driver
    driver.findElement(By.id("user")).sendKeys(user);
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(pass);
}
@Then("^I click on Login button$")
public void i_click_on_Login_button() throws Throwable {
    driver.findElement(By.id("btn")).click();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the  scenario with <kbd>Data Tables</kbd> to iterate the same step multiple times without closing the browser.

So change your feature file as below.

```
Feature: Login Scenario

Scenario: Execute me multiple times
    Given I open the application
    And validate the credentials
    | username | password  |
      | user1    | password1 |
      | user2    | password2 |
      | user3    | password3 |
    And I close the application
```

And then implement the stepdef as below.

```
@Given("validate the credentials:")
    public void validate_the_credentials(List<String> animals) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package steps;
import java.util.Map;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import cucumber.api.DataTable;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
public class Test {
WebDriver driver;
String gecko="webdriver.chrome.driver";
String path="./drivers/chromedriver1.exe";
@Given("^I open the application$")
public void i_open_the_application() throws Throwable {
    System.setProperty(gecko, path);
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("file:///C:/Users/AZ/Desktop/webpages/loginPage.html");
}
@When("^I enter username and password$")
public void i_enter_username_and_password(DataTable table) throws Throwable {
    for (Map<String,String> data : table.asMaps(String.class,String.class)) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("user")).sendKeys(data.get("username"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(data.get("password"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("btn")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
@When("^I close the application$")
public void i_close_the_application() throws Throwable {
    driver.close();
}
}
```